# Apollonius circle of three conics

Tags: geometry

I was thinking about the Apollonius problems, and then I asked if it can be "generalized" to others conics, so searching on the internet I found the next [paper](https://www.win.tue.nl/EWCG2005/Proceedings/38.pdf) that prove that there are at most 184 complex circles tangent to 3 conics in the plane, and said that know how many of these circles
can be real is an open question.

My question is if someone have more information about this, or know where can I find something related

Comment: Are the algebraico/geometric concepts/techniques evoked in this allusive paper already familiar to you (resultant, toric varieties, mixed volumes, Newton polygons, etc.) ? Is this really the question ?

Comment: Any comment ?...